# Android Intent setType and addCategory methods causing build errors

Tags: java, android, android-intent, build-error

I'm working on an application that I compiled using Website2Apk and reverse engineered to turn into a workable project within Android Studio. I started with 115 errors, and now I've narrowed it down to just eight. Six of these build errors are related to the setType and addCategory methods in one of the java files. I'm at a complete loss towards what could be causing these errors.

Here is my code for that specific java file:

```
package com.valen.plazaone;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.Object;

/* renamed from: com.valen.plazaone.c */
class C0002c extends WebChromeClient {
    final /* synthetic */ MainActivity f11a;

    C0002c(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.f11a = mainActivity;
    }

    private File m5a() {
        return File.createTempFile("JPEG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + "_", ".jpg", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
    }

    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String str, Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(str, true, false);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int i) {
        if (i < 100 && this.f11a.f4d.getVisibility() == 8) {
            this.f11a.f4d.setVisibility(0);
        }
        this.f11a.f4d.setProgress(i);
        if (i == 100) {
            this.f11a.f4d.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback valueCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        File a;
        Throwable e;
        Intent intent;
        Parcelable intent2;
        Parcelable[] parcelableArr;
        Object[] objArr;
        Intent intent3;
        if (this.f11a.f7h != null) {
            this.f11a.f7h.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        this.f11a.f7h = valueCallback;
        Intent intent4 = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        if (intent4.resolveActivity(this.f11a.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            try {
                a = m5a();
                try {
                    intent4.putExtra("PhotoPath", this.f11a.f8i);
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e = e2;
                    Log.e(MainActivity.f0f, "Unable to create Image File", e);
                    if (a != null) {
                        this.f11a.f8i = "file:" + a.getAbsolutePath();
                        intent4.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(a));
                    } else {
                        intent4 = null;
                    }
                    intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
                    intent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
                    intent2.addCategory();
                    intent2.setType("*/*");
                    if (intent == null) {
                        parcelableArr = new Intent[]{intent, intent4};
                    } else if (intent4 != null) {
                        objArr = new Intent[]{intent4};
                    } else {
                        parcelableArr = new Intent[0];
                    }
                    intent3 = new Intent("android.intent.action.CHOOSER");
                    intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", intent2);
                    intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TITLE", "Upload Files");
                    intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INITIAL_INTENTS", parcelableArr);
                    this.f11a.startActivityForResult(intent3, 1);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (IOException e3) {
                e = e3;
                a = null;
                Log.e(MainActivity.f0f, "Unable to create Image File", e);
                if (a != null) {
                    intent4 = null;
                } else {
                    this.f11a.f8i = "file:" + a.getAbsolutePath();
                    intent4.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(a));
                }
                intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
                intent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
                intent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.OPENABLE");
                intent2.setType("*/*");
                if (intent == null) {
                    parcelableArr = new Intent[]{intent, intent4};
                } else if (intent4 != null) {
                    parcelableArr = new Intent[0];
                } else {
                    objArr = new Intent[]{intent4};
                }
                intent3 = new Intent("android.intent.action.CHOOSER");
                intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", intent2);
                intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TITLE", "Upload Files");
                intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INITIAL_INTENTS", parcelableArr);
                this.f11a.startActivityForResult(intent3, 1);
                return true;
            }
            if (a != null) {
                this.f11a.f8i = "file:" + a.getAbsolutePath();
                intent4.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(a));
            } else {
                intent4 = null;
            }
        }
        intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
        intent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
        intent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.OPENABLE");
        intent2.setType("*/*");
        if (intent == null) {
            parcelableArr = new Intent[]{intent, intent4};
        } else if (intent4 != null) {
            objArr = new Intent[]{intent4};
        } else {
            parcelableArr = new Intent[0];
        }
        intent3 = new Intent("android.intent.action.CHOOSER");
        intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", intent2);
        intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TITLE", "Upload Files");
        intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INITIAL_INTENTS", parcelableArr);
        this.f11a.startActivityForResult(intent3, 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This specific error happens with all intent2's followed by a setType or addCategory. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual messaging of the error?

Comment: @cricket_007 The errors are as follows:

Error:(74, 28) error: cannot find symbol method addCategory()
Error:(75, 28) error: cannot find symbol method setType(String)
Error:(102, 24) error: cannot find symbol method addCategory(String)
Error:(103, 24) error: cannot find symbol method setType(String)
Error:(127, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addCategory(String)
Error:(128, 16) error: cannot find symbol method setType(String)

Comment: You made `Parcelable intent2`, then `intent2 = new Intent` and then `intent2.addCategory` and `intent2.setType`, so yes. `intent2` needs to be defined as `Intent intent2;`

Comment: @cricket_007 Now I have a new problem with my variable "parcelableArr" and some error saying IOException isn't declared.

Here's the error: Error:(86, 78) error: variable parcelableArr might not have been initialized
Error:(28, 35) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Error:(63, 19) error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: @cricket_007 never mind, I solved the error by making parcelableArr = Intent[0]; above the if for intent3. Now the only error is the one for IOException.

Answer (score 1):

Either change the declaration of the variable `intent2` from:

```
Parcelable intent2;
```

to:

```
Intent intent2;
```

Or if for some reason you cannot change that, type cast it to `Intent` whenever you are calling a method on it like:

```
((Intent) intent2).addCategory();
((Intent) intent2).setType("*/*");
```

Comment: @Nuovale Does this help?

Comment: The type cast option fixed my original problem, but now I have a new one. It says parcelableArr is not initialized, even though I'm pretty sure it is. It also says that IOException is never declared and must be "thrown in body of corresponding statement". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Never mind, I solved the error by making parcelableArr = Intent[0]; above the if for intent3. Now the only error is the one for IOException. Any idea on how to fix the IOException error?

Here's the error report:
Error:(28, 35) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Error:(63, 19) error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: Surround that piece of code with a try catch block.